# View commands performed by GitHub for Windows Client

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

Is there any way to see what commands the Github for Windows client is performing behind the scenes (e.g. some sort of debug mode)? I do use git from the command line as well but sometimes the GUI does multiple commands that aren't necessarily obvious so it would be helpful for informational/learning purposes to be able to see what the underlying commands are.

Comment: [The GitHub for Mac client uses libgit2](https://help.github.com/articles/is-there-a-way-to-see-what-git-commands-the-github-for-mac-app-is-executing/) and because of that you can't see the executed git commands. I don't know if the Windows client is build in the same way.

Comment: @dennisschagt Thanks for that. I followed up with GitHub support based on that and they were able to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to dennisschagt's comment, I checked with GitHub support on the matter and they said that GitHub for windows shells out to git.exe for some commands and uses [LibGitSharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) for others. In both cases, the commands are logged in %LocalAppData%\GitHub\thelog.txt.